# Python selenium - Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get screenshots of a website for a project I am doing. However, when I run my code, it works the first time and gives me the screenshot. However, when the code loops to take another screenshot, a very long error message comes up  saying that the connection has been refused. I am using python three and selenium on a macbook air

Here is my code

```
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument(f'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_0_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/chromedriver', options=options)

URL1 = 'https://www.accuweather.com/en/ie/moroe/1079356/current-weather/1079356'
URL2 = 'https://www.accuweather.com/en/ie/moroe/1079356/hourly-weather-forecast/1079356'
URL3 = 'https://weather.com/en-IE/weather/today/l/d71e95387799a552a061ec1550ac876dcc19b5d139adc6f51ba3b8bf7a6b96ed'
URL4 = 'https://weather.com/en-IE/weather/hourbyhour/l/d71e95387799a552a061ec1550ac876dcc19b5d139adc6f51ba3b8bf7a6b96ed#detailIndex4'
URL5 = 'https://www.met.ie/weather-forecast/moroe-limerick#forecasts'

while True:
    current_time = datetime.now()
    timenow = datetime.now()
    timenow = str(timenow)
    current_time = str(current_time)
    
    new_str = ""
    x = 0

    for i in range(0, len(current_time)):
        if i != 4 and i != 7 and i != 10 and i != 13 and i != 16:
            new_str = new_str + current_time[i]

    new_str = float(new_str)
    new_str = new_str / 100
    new_str = round(new_str, 0)
    if new_str % 2:
        x = x + 1
    else:        
        driver.get(URL1)

        S = lambda X: driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll'+X)
        driver.set_window_size(S('Width'),S('Height')) # May need manual adjustment                                                                                                                
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot('accu1' + timenow + '.png')
    
        driver.quit()

        time.sleep(61)
'''
        driver.get(URL2)

        S = lambda X: driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll'+X)
        driver.set_window_size(S('Width'),S('Height')) # May need manual adjustment                                                                                                                
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot('accu2' + timenow + '.png')
    
        driver.quit()

        driver.get(URL3)

        S = lambda X: driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll'+X)
        driver.set_window_size(S('Width'),S('Height')) # May need manual adjustment                                                                                                                
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot('weatherchannel1' + timenow + '.png')
    
        driver.quit()

        driver.get(URL4)

        S = lambda X: driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll'+X)
        driver.set_window_size(S('Width'),S('Height')) # May need manual adjustment                                                                                                                
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot('weatherchannel2' + timenow + '.png')
    
        driver.quit()

        driver.get(URL5)

        S = lambda X: driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll'+X)
        driver.set_window_size(S('Width'),S('Height')) # May need manual adjustment                                                                                                                
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot('meteireann' + timenow + '.png')
    
        driver.quit()
'''
```

and here is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1240, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1286, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1235, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1006, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 946, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 200, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb4e73fd490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hugophelan/Desktop/WeatherPiTest.py", line 39, in <module>
    driver.get(URL1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 78, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 375, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 573, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=54000): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/3bdcabee5f314f620196394cfedd7079/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb4e73fd490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

Comment: That's because you quit the connection, take a look [here](https://www.zyxware.com/articles/5552/what-is-close-and-quit-commands-in-selenium-webdriver) at what it does. Remove the line `driver.quit()`. and you should be fine. (Just keep the last one, when you really want to end the program)